# A Question on Maximum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $h : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be an analytic function such that $h(0) = 0; h( \frac{1}{2 }) = 5$, and $|h(z)| < 10$ for $|z| < 1.$
>
> Then, conclude that 
>   (a) the set $ \{z : |h(z)| = 5\}$ is unbounded by the Maximum Principle;
>
> (b) the set $\{z : |h ^{'}(z)| = 5\}$ is a circle of strictly positive radius;
>
> are both false statements

**My try:**
Since $h$ is non-constant in $|z|<1$; $|h|$ will not attain its maximum in $|z|<1$ by Maximum Modulus Principle.But I cant use this fact here.Any help.

Comment: Consider the function $$h(z)=10z$$